# Adding a section label over the staff

Tags: lilypond

I'm trying to add some text to mark the sections in the score, and I'm doing this with the `\sectionLabel` command. The following snippet doesn't seem to work though; no text appears at all. What am I missing?

```
\version "2.22.1"
\include "lilypond-book-preamble.ly"                                                                         

\score {
    \relative c'{
    \sectionLabel "Verse"
    e e e2 | e4 e e2 | e4 g c, d | e1 |
    }
}
```

I'm running GNU LilyPond 2.22.1 together with plain latex, installed on MacOS through homebrew.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `\section` and `\sectionLabel` are new. These commands don't exist in v2.22. You need to be running v2.23 for these command to work.

One way to tell this is by comparing these pages of the documentation:

- https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/writing-text
- https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/writing-text

The v2.22 page doesn't mention `\sectionLabels` at all, while the v2.23 page does.

---

I'm running v2.23 and your scrip works fine.

---

One workaround (if you don't want to upgrade to v2.23) is to change `\sectionLabel "Verse"` to `\mark "Verse"`.  The output won't be exactly the same, but it's very similar.

Comment: Thanks! I'll stick to the stable version, while learning the basics.